# knowing about Content Resolver in android

Tags: android

In android,there is a content provider and content resolver.I have seen many sites and books ,but not able to figure out clearly the difference b/w the two.
Can somebody tell me difference b/w the these two?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward... They work together, not alternatives to one another

> When you want to access data in a **content provider**, you use the **ContentResolver**

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) (emphasis mine)